# Compare dates using dayofyear() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to compare two dates trans-date and proc-date using dayofyear function. The function doesn’t work if the two dates are in separate years. Can anyone help me with that?
  Example:

```
trans-date = 2019-01-12”
Proc-date= “2020-01-01”

Dayofyear(trans-date)=12
Dayofyear (proc-date) = 1
```

Logically, proc-date is greater than trans-date but dayofyear doesn’t work that way. So, how can I calculate the dates where I can get trans-date < proc-date?
Thank you.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  Referencing a function that does not do what you want doesn't communicate very much.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample data and desired result.

Comment: *...dayofyear doesn’t work that way* so why do you want to compare the dates with this function?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to compare the month/date without the year.  If so, you date use `date_format()`:

```
where date_format(trans_date, '%Y-%m') < date_format(proc_date, '%Y-%m')
```